# XQueryTree is detecting a window twice

Tags: c++, qt, xlib

I'm working on a feature in my Qt program where you have the option to store the locations of your application's windows in a profile manner and load that profile later. After some research I found QSettings quite handy and useful for storing UI info like x, y etc. For detecting the windows I decided to use XLib.

I'm very beginner to using Xlib, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594184/getting-a-list-of-window-wids-in-qt) code which recursively query any open window starting from ":0.0". Inside the `foreach` loop I did this save function:

```
int x, y;
int xGeo, yGeo;
int width, height, border, depth;
Display *disp = XOpenDisplay(":0.0");
Window rootWin = XDefaultRootWindow(disp);
QList<Window> windows = listXWindowsRecursive(disp, rootWin);
char* name = NULL;
XWindowAttributes* attributes;
foreach(Window win, windows)
{
    attributes = new XWindowAttributes;
    // Enumerate through all windows
    if(XFetchName(disp, win, &name) && name != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, "Secondary Window") == 0)
        {
            Window child;
            qDebug() << (name);
            XTranslateCoordinates(disp, win, rootWin, 0, 0, &x, &y, &child);
            qDebug() << "XC  = " << x << " - " << "YC  = " << y;
            if(XGetGeometry(disp, win, &rootWin, &xGeo, &yGeo, &width, &height, &border, &depth))
                qDebug() << "XGeo= " << x - xGeo << " - " << "YGeo= " << y - yGeo;
            settings.setValue("secondaryWindow/x", x - xGeo);
            settings.setValue("secondaryWindow/y", y - yGeo);
            settings.setValue("secondaryWindow/width", width);
            settings.setValue("secondaryWindow/height", height);
            if(XGetWindowAttributes(disp, win, attributes))
            {
                qDebug() << "X  = " << x - attributes->x << " - " << "Y  = " << y - attributes->y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This portion gets the Qt UI info like X and Y and stores them using `QSettings`

First thing I'm not sure if what I wrote is the right way to get the X and Y for the window because of [these](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry) facts. Also I'm not sure if I'm correctly passing the required parameters.

Second thing, this is the load function:

```
if(settings.contains("secondaryWindow/x") && settings.contains("secondaryWindow/y"))
{
    SecondaryWindow* win = new SecondaryWindow;
    win->setGeometry(settings.value("secondaryWindow/x").toInt(),
                     settings.value("secondaryWindow/y").toInt(),
                     settings.value("secondaryWindow/width").toInt(),
                     settings.value("secondaryWindow/height").toInt());
    win->show();
}
```

Here is the weird scenario, there is a button that opens the secondary window (using `new` and `show`) which works fine. Back to the main window clicking the save function, I get the correct secondary window info.

Now If I closed the secondary window and then clicked the load function, the secondary window opens correctly in the previous position BUT, clicking the save function again here will tell me that there are two "Secondary Window" instances but the second one has X and Y = 0.

By "closing the window" I mean using either the "X" button and using the `close()` slot. Could it be that the window is not closed correctly? I already implemented the `closeEvent` handler:

```
event->accept();
QWidget::closeEvent(event);
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It is `c++`, you should free unused memory and destroy objects by hand, or use `smart pointers` or use `Qt` parent child track system, any way `SecondaryWindow* win = new SecondaryWindow;` for any create by `new` object you should call `delete` in implicit or explicit way.

Comment: And the second problem I you need `XQueryTree` at all? There is qt `mapToGlobal`, there is `geometry` methods, why you need such strange way to get coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure about this `mapToGlobal` method, but I want to get all the opened windows from my application from a single point that's why I traverse all open windows using `XQueryTree`. I used `XFetchName` to identify my windows because `XQueryTree` will return other unusual stuff.

Comment: Then use `QApplication::topLevelWidgets` and `mapToGlobal` to convert local `QWidget` coordinate to global "display" coordinate system. And free memory, `close` not free memory allocated by `new`

Comment: You saved a lot of work with your solution!, using `widget->pos()` returned the x and y of the display coordinates system and `widget->windowTitle()` returned the window title which is what I need!. I'm testing few things now and will be back with any feedback, thanks a lot :D